# How can I store an image in the database with Transients API?

Tags: images, database, transient

I'm trying to store an image generated with [`imagecreatefrompng()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) using the [Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API), but it just stores an empty string (`string(0) ""`). Also, I notice if I set the transient before `imagedestroy( $im )`, the image is broken and doesn't display at all (broken image thumbnail).

What *can* I store in the database with the Transients API? How would I store an image like described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imagecreatefrom*` functions return an image resource identifier, which when cast to a string (saving an option) will result in an empty `string(0) ""` container.

Raw images created by these functions do not have any specific data structure that can be serialized out of the box. Two solutions I can think of:

### image files

Use [`imagepng`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php), for example to get the actual PNG data and store that instead.

```
$image_resource = imagecreatefrompng( ... );

// do GD manipulations

$temp = tempnam( sys_get_temp_dir(), 'image_cache_' );
imagepng ( $image_resource, $temp );

$image_data = file_get_contents( $temp );
set_transient( 'cached_image', base64_encode( $image_data ), 3600 );

unlink( $temp );
```

Remember to always [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) the data, since the options table in WordPress has `LONGTEXT` type data fields which is not binary-ready.

Also note how you can maybe cache the image data in the uploads folder instead and use the Transients API to cache their image names:

```
$image_resource = imagecreatefrompng( ... );

// do GD manipulations

$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$upload_file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $unique_image_name;

imagepng ( $image_resource, $upload_file );

set_transient( 'cached_image', $upload_file, 3600 );
```

### dumping pixels

If, for one reason or another, you require to actually store raw pixel RGBA structures then you'll need to use the [`imagecolorat`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorat.php) and read each and every pixel of the image, create a huge array and serialize it. Retrieving this data will require the rebuilding of the image.

This method has a very high overhead, can get confusing with color allocations and alpha blending, so in short, should not be used.

Comment: Your first solution works wonderfully for what I need. I picture my script working like this: It uses query vars to build an image dynamically, so I make an array of the query vars, sort them A-Z, turn it into a query string. SHA1 the query string (use that as the _name_ of the transient) and `base64_encode` the image data, then use `imagecreatefromstring()` to display the image from the transient data. Viola!

Comment: To prevent loss of data, you might want to serialize any string based stuff you put in the database, in this case the base64 encoded string. Refer to [serialize](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), [unserialize](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) and [maybe_serialize](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/maybe_serialize).